# Sign of square free integer which makes elliptic curves rank $0$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an arbitrary elliptic curve.

It is known that there exists a square-free integer such that $rank(E_D/\mathbb{Q}) = 0$.

Is it known whether there exists a positive $D$ such that $rank(E_D/\mathbb{Q}) = 0$ and, similarly, a negative $D$ for which $rank(E_D/\mathbb{Q}) = 0$?

Comment: I would guess “yes” on both counts, though I do not know of a reference. Maybe start from Murty, Murty, “Nonvanishing of quadratic twists of modular L-functions” (then apply Gross-Zagier-Kolyvagin+… [or just Kato]).